# Changing color of a viewController from another viewController button

Tags: swift

I have the main viewController that segues to a settingsViewController.  In the settingsViewController is a button I want when pressed, to change the background color of the main viewController. How do I do this in Swift?

Thank you.

Comment: You could save the color to NSUserDefaults or as an app delegate variable or something like that

Comment: Ok, I'm totally new to Swift.  I Googled both the things you mentioned and can't find example code.  Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one way to set the color in the settingsViewController and retrieve it in the other view controller is to use NSUserDefaults. Set the object for key to the color you want and then use NSUserDefaults to access it in the other view. NSUserDefaults persists so you don't have to worry about saving it, because it is already saved by the system. NSUserDefaults is not good for large amounts of data, but it works fine for simple settings such as a color. You can only set plist object to NSUserDefaults (ie. Strings, Ints, NSData, etc...) so you must use NSKeyedArchiver to package a color as NSData or store RGB color values individually

```
// In your settings view controller
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(UIColor.blueColor()), forKey: "color")

// In your other view controller's viewDidLoad (most likely)
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let data = defaults.objectForKey("color") as? NSData {
    if let colorFromData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? UIColor {
        homeCollectionView.backgroundColor = colorFromData
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the items above you mentioned.  It does not like the 'homeCollectionView.backgroundColor = colorFromData' line.  It brought up the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'homeCollectionView'.  Does it need to be the name of my main ViewController, so in this case 'ViewController.swift'?

Comment: That line was where I set the color to test it in my view controller. You'll have to change it to fit your view controller because that collection view doesn't exist in yours

Comment: Probably just view.backGroundColor = ... Or something like that for yours